Session information can be accessed with Postman but not from the front end
I am developing a web application with NodeJs. I save the session information to the session object in the login function, but this value returns undefined in the requests I make from the front end. I configured CORS settings on the NodeJs side but the result is the same. But when I send the same request with Postman, it works smoothly. Can you offer any solution or can I do this in a different way?
The login function code I use in the router is as follows:
exports.loginWithLdap = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  if (!username || !password) {
    return next(new AppError('Please provide username and password!', 404));
  }
  const user = await ldapService.authenticate(username, password);
  if (!user) {
    return next(new AppError('Ldap authentication failed!', 401));
  }
  const otp = await otpService.generateAndSaveOTP(user.mail);

  await otpService.sendOTP(user.mail, otp);
  req.session.user = user;
  
  res.cookie('user', user, { httpOnly: true });
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    message: 'OTP sent successfully!',
  });
});

My cors and session settings are as follows:
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:5173', 
    credentials: true, 
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE', 
  })
);

app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'yourSecretKey',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: false,
      sameSite: 'none',
      maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    },
  })
);

app.use('/api', userRouter);

And i am trying to read req.session.user in this function:
exports.verifyOtp = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.session.user);
  const { otp } = req.body;
  if (!otp) {
    return next(
      new AppError('Please provide an OTP code for authentication!', 404)
    );
  }
  await otpService.verifyOTP(req.session.user.mail, otp);

  res
    .status(200)
    .json({ message: 'OTP verified successfully!', user: req.session.user });
});

I tried to send request from Postman and it works fine. After that updated cors and session setings many times because i think that might be the problem. But it doesn't work at all.

add this to your request header Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
and check this out maybe helps to you
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin
